# ActiveAdminでfriendly_idを使っているモデルのパンくずリストが別の物を指してしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

`code`というカラムを持つ`Company`モデルがあり、`friendly_id`を使っています。

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :code, use: :slugged
end
```

そこで`ActiveAdmin`を使い始めたのですが、何も設定しないと`friendly_id`を認識せずに間違ったインスタンスを取得してしまうので

```
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
  controller do
    def find_resource
      scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

として編集などの作業は問題なく行えるようになりました。
ただこの記述を追加しても`edit`のページで表示されるパンくずリストは`friendly_id`を経由せずに無関係のものを取得してきてしまうようです。

パンくずリストも`friendly_id`を考慮して取得するにはどこにどのような記述をついかすればいいのでしょうか？

#### 追記

回答が得られませんでしたので、英語版の方に同様の質問をいたしました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200799/breadcrumbs-list-in-activeadmin-shows-wrong-name-when-using-friendly-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語版で回答を頂いたのでこちらにも書いておきます。

`lib/active_admin/dsl.rb`に以下の記述があるので、これに従えばパンくずリストを任意に変更できます。

```
# Rewrite breadcrumb links.
# Block will be executed inside controller.
# Block must return an array if you want to rewrite breadcrumb links.
#
# Example:
#   ActiveAdmin.register Post do
#     breadcrumb do
#       [
#         link_to('my piece', '/my/link/to/piece')
#       ]
#     end
#   end
#
def breadcrumb(&block)
  config.breadcrumb = block
end
```

実際に以下のようなコードで希望する動作が確認できました。

#### app/admin/companies.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  breadcrumb do
    links = [link_to('Admin', admin_root_path), link_to('Companies', admin_companies_path)]
    if %(show edit).include?(params['action'])
      links << link_to(company.name, admin_company_path)
    end
    links
  end
end
```